# Ubuntu VM: Wifi Adapter not found

Tags: wireless, virtualbox

I am new to Linux and started with Ubuntu.
I am facing issue with wifi driver.
I Have installed the Ubuntu on Windows 10 host virtual box.

I have connected to wifi network and I can access internet from Ubuntu guest OS.
But when I go to Ubuntu settings and find wifi - it shows

```
wifi adapter not found. Please plug in and turn ON.
```

When I go to network setting it shows `connected` `wired`.

How can I install or enable wifi driver in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: There shouldn't be WiFi in a virtual machine. It uses the host system connection. It is shown as wired.

Answer (score 2):

The HOST (Windows) owns the WiFi adapter. Any WiFi driver should be installed on the HOST.

The Virtualbox on the HOST relays the WiFi network connection to the GUEST...but that relay appears as a wired connection.

Your Ubuntu GUEST cannot see the WiFi adapter or network. That is normal, expected behavior. You Ubuntu system sees only the pseudo-wired connection provided by VirtualBox.

That's what virtualization means.

Your Ubuntu GUEST cannot control any hardware. It sees only the pseudo-hardware provided by Virtualbox on the HOST. The HOST retains control of all hardware.

Comment: You can, however, add a usb WiFi adapter and dedicate it's use to the Guest.

Comment: @Eagle_Mike go ahead and add the instructions as your own answer.